# More efficient switch case?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've looked all over for this but perhaps I'm not using the correct terminology. This seems like a very inefficient way to check through an array of 3 strings.

I am looking at each item in the array and checking for a value individually. Is there a shorter way to achieve the same result?

```
$j = get_field('loan_types');
$business = '<i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>';
$property = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';
$personal = '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>';
switch ($j[0]) {
  case 'Business':
    echo $business;
    break;
  case 'Personal':
    echo $personal;
    break;
  case 'Property':
    echo $property;
    break;
}
switch ($j[1]) {
  case 'Business':
    echo $business;
    break;
  case 'Personal':
    echo $personal;
    break;
  case 'Property':
    echo $property;
    break;
}
switch ($j[2]) {
  case 'Business':
    echo $business;
    break;
  case 'Personal':
    echo $personal;
    break;
  case 'Property':
    echo $property;
    break;
}
```

Comment: A switch inside a `foreach()` loop? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$j` is an array, you can use a foreach loop, like so:

```
$j = get_field('loan_types');
$business = '<i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>';
$property = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>';
$personal = '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>';

foreach ($j as $loan_field) {
  switch ($loan_field) {
    case 'Business':
      echo $business;
      break;
    case 'Personal':
      echo $personal;
      break;
    case 'Property':
      echo $property;
      break;
  }
}
```

Edit: If you're really feeling adventurous, see CBroe' great answer!

Comment: Thank you, I've picked up php from various sources and have never done anything with foreach. Now I understand it clearly - very helpful!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: If `$j` gets bigger also, you won't need to add anything

Answer (score 3):

How about you do away with the whole `switch` statement to begin with …?

If you place the values you want to output in an associative array, and use the loan type as key, then you can have this as short as

```
$j = get_field('loan_types');
$icons = array(
  'Business' => '<i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>',
  'Property' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>',
  'Personal' => '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>',
);

foreach($j as $loan_field) {
  if(isset($icons[$loan_field])) {
    echo $icons[$loan_field];
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, you beat me to my edit. I'll remove mine and link to yours!

Comment: Great to see the alternative, will do away with the switch statement entirely.